# Export to pdf with range selection cell in one page

Tags: vba, excel

I can not export to PDF, in horizontal format all my range selection, Where am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Macro()
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Set wksht = ActiveSheet

Dim path As String
path = "C:\test\"

If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir path
End If

Dim rngeStart
Dim rngeEnd

Set rngeStart = wksht.UsedRange.Find(What:="####", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set rngeEnd = wksht.UsedRange.FindNext(After:=rngeStart)

Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = wksht.Range(rngeStart, rngeEnd)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To wksht.Range("A" & wksht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  wksht.Copy
  With ActiveSheet
     .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, rngeStart.Column - 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
     .Rows("1:" & rngeStart.Row - 1).Delete
End With
```

This part for Export in PDF, only one page without all range selection:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).Value & ".pdf", _ Quality:=xlQualityStandard,
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False 
ActiveWorkbook.Close 
  Next i
End Sub
```

is there a function "fit to onepage" export in pdf?

Comment: Can you expand on the problem? Why "can you not"?

Comment: Not Work, export only one page in vertical @ashleedawg

Comment: Have you changed your page layout settings?

Comment: @Olly i can not do it

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Are you trying to do it manually, but you don't know how? Are you trying to do it programatically, and if so, do you not how how, or is there an error, or is there no error but unexpected results?

Comment: @Olly this is my pdf export [link](https://files.fm/u/mg8x49uy)  I would like everything in one page or in landscape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to adjust the activesheet format before pdf export ?
Please add this code in the begining of your sub Macro() :

```
'START FORMAT THE ACTIVE SHEET
Application.PrintCommunication = False

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
    .Orientation = xlLandscape 'xlPortrait
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = True
'END FORMAT THE ACTIVE SHEET
```

Comment: Great happy to help you